# SharePoint Tables - Build URL using Project ID

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, powerquery, m

I am trying to connect to a Sharepoint project.

This is the function that I have created.

```
(ReqURL as text, ReqTitle as text) =>
let
    Source = SharePoint.Tables(ReqURL, [ApiVersion = 15]),
    ReqData = Source{[Title=ReqTitle]}[Items]
in
    ReqData
```

https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/sandbox100pwa/projectA/

But I don't want to pass the name of the Project (ProjectA) in the URL, but rather the project ID.

This is the project ID - **1100bd58-9019-f811-bgbd-00255e60673e**

I am trying to pass the URL like,

https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/sandbox100pwa/ProjUid=1100bd58-9019-f811-bgbd-00255e60673e/

and it is not working, what I am doing wrong here.